# Understand the corrispondence between rational maps and linear systems.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, surfaces, schemes, birational-geometry

A key fact in "birational geometry" (on $\mathbb C$) is the following theorem:

> Let S be a surface. Then there is a bijection between the following
> sets:
>
> (i) {rational maps  $\phi:S-\rightarrow\mathbb P^n $ such that $\phi(S)$ is contained in no hyperplane}.
>
> (ii) {linear systems on $S$ without fixed part and of
> dimension $n$}.

The statement of the theorem is taken from the Beauville's book on algebraic surfaces, but the result is true even if we replace $S$ with a generic non-singular projective variety.

On Beauville's book there is a quick proof (only for surfaces), and unfortunately most of the details are not covered. I have understood how the bijective correspondence is constructed, but I have missed some things. For example:

$1)$ Why do we require that $\phi(S)$ is not contained in any hyperplane?

$2)$ Let  $P$ be a linear system on $S$ and let $x\in S$ be a closed point. why the set
$$\{D\in\text{Div}(S)\,: x\; \text{is in the support of}\;D\}$$
is a hyperplane of $P$?

So my request is the following:

> I'd like to see a complete proof of the theorem for the general case (not only for surfaces). So, I need a direct proof here on ME or alternatively a reference. If there will be two distinct answers, one with a reference and one with a proof, I clearly will accept the proof.

Comment: Let me just answer your example questions. 1. If $\phi(S)$ is contained in a hyperplane, then there is a linear relation between the divisors in the linear system. So the linear system is of dimension at most $n-1$ in that case. 2. Near $x$ any divisor in the linear system is the zero set of some regular function. So let $D_0, \ldots, D_n$ be a basis of the linear system and $f_0,\ldots,f_n$ the corresponding functions. Then your set is exactly $\{ \sum_i \lambda_i D_i \mid \sum_i \lambda_i f_i(x) =0\}$. This is one linear condition on the $\lambda_i$. Note though that if $x$ is a basepoint

Comment: of the system then $f_i(x)=0$ for all $i$ so this condition is empty: that means that your set is the whole linear system, not a hyperplane.

Comment: Your statement in question 2) is not correct. It is $\{D\in P\colon x\in\mathrm{Supp}(D)\}$ which is a hyperplane of $P$ (provided that $x$ is not a base-point of $P$): If you write a basis of sections for $P$ then the condition of vanishing at $x$ is given by a single linear equation.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be a linear system on $X$ with no fixed part. Say $S=\Bbb{P}(V)$ with $V\subset H^0(X,L)$ for some line bundle $L$ on $X$. Then the choice of a basis for $V$ gives you a rational map from $X$ to $\Bbb{P}(V)$. The points where the map is not defined is the set of base-points of $S$. Notice that if the image of this map was contained in a hyperplane it would mean that the elements of your basis are linearly dependent.

If you have a rational map $\varphi$ from $X$ to some $\Bbb{P}^n$ then define $L:=\varphi^\ast\mathcal{O}(1)$ and $V:=\varphi^\ast H^0(\Bbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(1))$. So you have $H^0(X,L)=V\oplus W$ (with $W$ possibly zero). Then you have a linear system $S=\Bbb{P}(V)$ and by construction its associated map, up to a change of basis of $V$, is $\varphi$.